# python subprocess Process target function won't instantiate classes

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to launch several operations in parallel using `subprocess.Process`. The problem I am having is that if I try to instantiate an instance of my class in the target function nothing happens. But, if I instantiate the classes first and pass the instances to the target function then everything works. Here is an abstraction of what I am doing

**Instantiate before launching Process: everything works**

```
def spawn(my_class_instance):
    my_class_instance.launch()

for params in my_list_of_parameters:
   an_instance = MyClass(params)
   Process(target=spawn, args=(an_instance)).start()
```

**Instantiate inside target function: doesn't work**

```
def spawn(params):
   an_instance = MyClass(params)
   an_instance.launch()

for params in my_list_of_parameters:
   Process(target=spawn, args=(params)).start()
```

I'd really like to understand more about *why* it doesn't work to try to instantiate classes inside the target function. Is it related to immediately calling `Process.start()`? What is happening under the hood that is preventing this?

One thing that might be causing this is that each `MyClass.launch()` itself calls `subprocess.Popen(..., shell=False)`, in case this might be the reason. If so, why? It still gets called in the first case.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? How are you checking that? I've just tried it myself and it works fine both ways. Do you see any errors or anything?

Comment: @ojii `MyClass.launch()` does a lot of stuff, prints logs to screen, writes files...when I run `python my_script.py` with the second version nothing prints to console and execution stops and I get back to my ordinary terminal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works. Still, I may be something in your question.

```
from multiprocessing import Process

class MyClass:
  def __init__(self, params):
    pass

  def launch(self):
    print "method launch is called"

def spawn(params):
  an_instance = MyClass(params)
  an_instance.launch()

my_list_of_parameters  = ['1', '2']

for params in my_list_of_parameters:
   Process(target=spawn, args=(params)).start()
```